# EAR File: Where does the jaxb.properties file go

Tags: jaxb

If I have a EAR file as follows...

```
EAR
  EJB
  JAR
  WAR
```

Where would I put the jaxb.properties file ./? ./JAR/? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jaxb.properties` should be in the same package as one of the classes used to bootstrap the JAXBContext. Read [this blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html) for more details

Comment: +1 - And in this post I have an exploded view of where the `jaxb.properties` file would go when your application is packaged as a WAR:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html